# PHP y la función header(location: )

Tags: php, funciones

Tengo un hosting de Hostgator en el cual siempre tengo el mismo problema al usar la función header de php para re-direccionar, por ej:
header("Location:index.php");
Si lo hago en xampp, no hay problemas y todo funciona bien, pero si lo subo al hosting, siempre recibo el warning que dice "headers already sent... bla bla bla". Siempre pasa, apenas uso la función header("Location:archivo.php") recibo el warning y no me re-direcciona.
¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Aquí va mi código

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Lista de Precios</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-image: url('img/fondo-hawaii.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    table, tr, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;


     }
     tr td {
      max-width: 20%;
     }
     tr td:nth-child(1) {
  max-width: 10%;
}
     .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n) > td, .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n) > th {
   background-color: #fff;
    }
    .table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
 .primera_fila {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #D4D4D4;
 }   
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-8">
    <img src="img/logo-halo-hawaii.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
   &nbsp;
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2"></div>
 </div>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">ACTUALIZAR</h1>

<?php
  include("conexion.php");
  if (!isset($_POST["bot_actualizar"])) {
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    $nombre=$_GET["nombre"];
    $precio=$_GET["precio"];
    $fabricante=$_GET["fabricante"];  
  }else{
    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $precio=$_POST["precio"];
    $fabricante=$_POST["fabricante"];
    $sql="UPDATE precios SET nombre=:minom, precio=:mipre, fabricante=:mifab WHERE id=:miid";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->execute(array(":miid"=>$id, ":minom"=>$nombre, ":mipre"=>$precio, ":mifab"=>$fabricante));
    header("Location:index.php");
  }

?>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <table  class="table  table-hover table-striped" style="width: 60%;" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><label for="id"></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td><label for="nombre"></label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apellido</td>
      <td><label for="precio"></label>
      <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value="<?php echo $precio ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dirección</td>
      <td><label for="fabricante"></label>
      <input type="text" name="fabricante" id="fabricante" value="<?php echo $fabricante ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="bot_actualizar" id="bot_actualizar" value="Actualizar"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

En github: https://github.com/ashcrimson/halohawaii/blob/master/editar.php

Comment: Deberías comprobar que la función `header` está antes de cualquier respuesta del tipo `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump`, etc. Una respuesta `http`envía primero las cabeceras y después el contenido. Si se intenta añadir o modificar las cabeceras después de haberlas enviado suele dar este tipo de errores. Es cuestión de comprobar el flujo de la web o aplicación en el tramo de código que comenta @Mariano.

Comment: @FelipePino Deberías considerar en aceptar cualquiera de las respuesta que te ayudo a resolver el problema por el esfuerzo y el tiempo que se dedicaron en responder tu pregunta saludos :)

Comment: Te recomendaria que uses una acción Ajax para para el evento editar de esta manera no tendras la logia en la vista.

Comment: Les agradezco inmensamente sus respuestas, lo solucione al eliminar los espacios.

Answer (score 30):

Al contrario de lo que dicen algunas respuestas, **no deberías ocultar la advertencia**. Está ahí por un motivo y te ofrece una descripción clara de por qué no funciona. La advertencia que estás recibiendo se debe a que se están enviando encabezados luego de haber enviado el cuerpo del HTML... ya es tarde.

---

#### Redireccionar con [header('Location: ...')](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)

[`header()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) envía los [encabezados HTTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabeceras_HTTP) y **debe ser lo primero que envía el server**, antes de cualquier otra declaración, sin siquiera líneas en blanco antes. Además, para algunos navegadores, la URL a la que se desea redireccionar no puede ser una ruta relativa, **debe ser una ruta absoluta**.

```
header('Location: http://tuweb.com/pagina.html');
die();
```

Y con `die()` terminamos inmediatamente la ejecución del script, evitando que se envíe más salida al cliente. Sin embargo, es mejor envíar un mensaje notificando que se ha redireccionado con un enlace para seguir, en caso de que no funcione el redireccionamiento automático. Por ejemplo

```
header('Location: http://tuweb.com/pagina.html');
echo "El recurso se ha movido hacia <a href=\"http://tuweb.com/pagina.html\">aquí</a>."
die();
```

Por ejemplo, si quisiéramos redireccionar a una página dentro de la ruta actual, independientemente de cuál sea la ruta:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ruta = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$html = 'pagina.html';
$url = "http://$host$ruta/$html";
header("Location: $url");
echo "El recurso se ha movido hacia <a href=\"$url\">aquí</a>."
die();
```

En tu caso, el código PHP debería estar al principio del archivo.

---

**Nota:** Algunos servicios de hosting envían headers por su cuenta, haciendo que sea imposible redireccionar mediante encabezados. Las alternativas son:

Con una etiqueta META en el HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Location" content="http://tuweb.com/pagina.html"/>
```

o mediante JavaScript

```
window.location.replace("http://tuweb.com/pagina.html");
```

La recomendación más robusta es que utilices todas las variantes, por si alguna falla. Por ejemplo

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ruta = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$html = 'pagina.html';
$url = "http://$host$ruta/$html";

header("Location: $url");
include redirect.php;
die();
```

Y el codigo de `redirect.php` sería:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Location" content="<?= $url ?>"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.replace("<?= $url ?>");
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    El recurso se ha movido hacia <a href="<?= $url ?>">aquí</a>.
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 8):

Tal como se venía comentando en los comentarios y respuestas.

Es cuestión de poner el código `php` antes del `html`.

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
if(!isset($_POST["bot_actualizar"])) {
    $id         = $_GET["id"];
    $nombre     = $_GET["nombre"];
    $precio     = $_GET["precio"];
    $fabricante = $_GET["fabricante"];
}
else {
    $id         = $_POST["id"];
    $nombre     = $_POST["nombre"];
    $precio     = $_POST["precio"];
    $fabricante = $_POST["fabricante"];
    $sql        = "UPDATE precios SET nombre=:minom, precio=:mipre, fabricante=:mifab WHERE id=:miid";
    $resultado  = $base->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->execute(array(":miid"  => $id,
                              ":minom" => $nombre,
                              ":mipre" => $precio,
                              ":mifab" => $fabricante
    ));
    header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- //... resto del código -->
```

Eso debería solucionarlo.

Y revisando el resto de archivos, deberías de cambiarlo en todos para evitar otros errores. El código que ejecutas no necesita estar mezclado con el html.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! es tal como tú decías. Puse todo el código php al principio del archivo y se solucionó. Estaba leyendo PHP & MySQL For Dummies y ahí también salía lo del error "headers already sent" y justo decían lo de que no debían haber espacios ni nada antes. Aún así no se me ocurrió que la cosa era tan simple como poner todo el php al principio, como que asumí que el navegador debe leer todo de arriba a abajo y no iba a funcionar.

Solucionado.

Comment: @FelipePino Deberias seleccionar la pregunta que soluciono o ayudo tu problema, y a las demás quizás una más 1 por la dedicación al problema. Saludos :)

Comment: @OscarR En alguna ocasión se me ha complicado mucho el tema de tener que meter el header("location...") dentro de una condición y a la vez tener que subirlo arriba del todo el archivo y ademas usar lo de las rutas absolutas, es un poco follón. Hay alguna manera facil con PHP de hacer esto? Librerías, o hacer un echo de Javascript con un location o algo similar que haga las redirecciones más sencillas? Da la sensación de ser PHP un lenguaje que tiende a enguarrecer el código.

Comment: @Lorthas siempre se necesita algo de planificación para realizar cambios similares a los que comentas. Al ser lenguaje de servidor, cualquier condicional puede ir siempre antes que cualquier parte de html. Sobre las rutas absolutas, quizás [esto puede servir de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75917/5984).

Answer (score 7):

Aunque la función **header()** No es para mostrar un error grave al menos que no este escrito bien o no de la manera correta es algo similar con el require cuando el archivo no existe este muestra un error grave y no ejecuta la aplicación.

Podrías mostrar el código donde se encuentra la función **header()** para analizar más a fondo el error?

Recuerda que **header()** debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde PHP. Es un error muy común leer código con funciones como include o require, u otro tipo de funciones de acceso de ficheros que incluyen espacios o líneas en blanco que se muestran antes de llamar a la función **header().** Sucede el mismo problema cuando se utiliza un solo fichero PHP/HTML.

```
<html>
<?php
/* Esto producirá un error. Fíjese en el html
 * que se muestra antes que la llamada a header() */
 header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Comment: @FelipePino  Tal como lo indique el problema esta que la función `header()` se encuentra dentro de la etiqueta `html` esto mostrara un error, debes colocar el código `PHP` antes del `html`

Answer (score 3):

A mi me pasaba eso también.

Al inicip del archivo añade

```
<?php ob_start() ?>
```

y al final

```
<?php ob_end_flush();?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
//aquí tu codigo php
?>
//aquí todo lo relacionado con html.
```

Tu código PHP debe de ir al principio, antes de tu HTML para que tu pantalla esté limpia, y el `header` funcione. A mí me funcionó, ojalá y te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

En vez de poner `header("Location:index.php");`
en esa linea puedes poner:

```
echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Conexion exitosa");
window.location.href="index.php";</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaria que uses una acción Ajax para para el evento editar de esta manera no tendras la logia en la vista,  si tu action es exitosa puede redireccionar con javascript por ejemplo:

```
//JavaScript
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".btn_actualizar").click(function() {
   var parameter = {
    id : $(".txtId").val()
    nombre: $(".txtNombre").val()
    precio:$(".txtPrecio").val()
    fabricante:$("txtFabricante").val()
    }
    $.ajax({
    data: parameter,
    url: '../controller/update.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    },
    error: function(response) {
     alert(response)
    }
    })
   })
})
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <input value="Nombre" type="text" class="txtNombre">
<!-- //... resto del código -->
    <button value="Editar" class="btn_actualizar"/>
<!-- //... resto del código -->
// Codigo PHP
// update.php
<?php
include("conexion.php");

    $id         = $_POST["id"];
    $nombre     = $_POST["nombre"];
    $precio     = $_POST["precio"];
    $fabricante = $_POST["fabricante"];
    $sql        = "UPDATE precios SET nombre=:minom, precio=:mipre, fabricante=:mifab WHERE id=:miid";
    $resultado  = $base->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->execute(array(":miid"  => $id,
                              ":minom" => $nombre,
                              ":mipre" => $precio,
                              ":mifab" => $fabricante
    ));
  #resto del código
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Colocalo antes del doc, cuándo los subes a hosting el lo toma literalmente como un cabeza de página por lo tanto tiene que colocarse ahí, a diferencia que en el localhost lo jala cómo un header

Answer (score -1):

Depende del nivel de visualización de los WARNING en la configuración de tu archivo php.ini.

En tu caso, tendrás una configuración diferente en Xampp y el tu Hosting. Copia la configuración de tu archivo php.ini y pone en contacto con tu proveedor de Hosting para que te iguale la configuración.

Comment: Si se trata de ocultar errores, se tarda menos en hacer algo así: `@header("Location:index.php");` pero esto no soluciona el problema. Desde el punto de vista de _las buenas prácticas_ la ocultación de errores no es una de ellas.

Comment: Tampoco se trata de un error, es una advertencia y se puede configurar el nivel de estos avisos a gusto del administrador (y bajo su responsabilidad, claro está). Buen aporte lo del `@header` .

Comment: Según entendí, el problema no es cómo esconder la advertencia, sino cómo redireccionar correctamente

Answer (score -1):

Me pasa lo mismo y probe todas las opciones de este hilo pero solo me funciono esta:

```
<?php ob_start() ?>
```

y

```
<?php ob_end_flush();?>
```

Comment: Por favor no dupliques respuestas, si alguna te funciono entonces cuando puedas solo dale un +1