# header php me dejó de funcionar

Tags: php, redirección

Estoy desarrollando un carrito de compras online. En la última página, donde se confirma el pedido, tras todos los datos en la base llamo a una función terminar() que me descarga alguna variables y me redirecciona al index.php

Desde que subí la prueba al servidor dejó de funcionar y me sale un error en la línea donde redirecciono.
Copio el código :

```
function terminar() {

        global $mi_carrito;
        unset ($mi_carrito);
        $_SESSION["carrito"] = null;
        $_SESSION["cuenta_items"]=null;
        $_SESSION["pedido_total"]=null;
        $_SESSION["pedido_total2"]=null;
        header('Location: index.php');    
}
```

Comment: ¿Que error te aparece?

Comment: Intenta poner la url completa del la página donde quieres redireccionar.
<?php header('Location: http://localhost:8080/app/index.php'); ?>

Comment: posible duplicado: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19791/php-y-la-funci%C3%B3n-headerlocation/19801

Answer (score 1):

Deberías añadir el error que te aparece.

Lo más probable es que hayas mandado contenido antes de mandar las cabeceras.

Asegúrate de que

- No envías contenido previo
- Usas UTF8 sin BOM
- No has mandado cabeceras previamente

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que para que funcione el `header` tienes que no haber impreso nada en pantalla.

Para más información inspecciona el código del sitio en el que se queda.

Comment: Hola como estan ... recien leo, no entiendo el criterio de que no es clara mi pregunta , es exactamente lo que expuse , ayer dejó de funcionar y me marca error  en el header location .

Les copio el error :

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/bureaude/public_html/bureauderegalos/finaliza2.php:458) in /home/bureaude/public_html/bureauderegalos/finaliza2.php on line 128

Comment: La linea 128 es la del header location, la 458 es la llamada a esa funcion.

Comment: `Warning: Cannot modify header information` , estas imprimiendo algo o ese error sale cuando has impreso algo por pantalla y no deja trabajar al header , el header hay que tener en cuenta que es el primer elemento que tiene que aparecer en la página , si quieres que redirija algún sitio.