# Redireccionar acceso con sesiones

Tags: php

Al ingresar el usuario y la clave válidos, el sistema crea una variable CONTROL a la que se le asigna el valor de 1.
LOGIN.PHP:

```
<?php
    require ('includes/config.php');    
    if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
        $usuariodao = new UsuarioDAO();
        $u = $usuariodao->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['password']);
        if($u){
            $_SESSION['USUARIO_ACTUAL'] = serialize($u);
            $_SESSION['CONTROL'] = 1;
            header("Location: index2.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            $tpl = new Plantilla();
            $tpl->assign('ErrorLogin', "Usuario y/o Clave incorrectos");
            $tpl->display("login.tpl.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

INDEX2.PHP:

```
<?php
    require ('includes/config.php');
    if ($_SESSION['CONTROL'] !== 1) {
        header("Location: index.php");  <-- EJECUTAR SI "CONTROL" no fue definido.
        exit;
    }
    echo "EXITO";
//---- CODIGO QUE SE EJECUTARÁ
?>
```

Si la clave y usuario son correctos muestra "EXITO" y en la barra queda: http://localhost/index2.php
Pero si abro otra ventana y copio el url igual muestra "EXITO". No entra a ejecutar INDEX.PHP.
Pero si cierro el navegador y pego el url http://localhost/index2.php sí ejecuta el header redireccionando a index.php. Cuál es el problema??

Comment: Parece que estas en un bucle de redireccionamiento infinito. Haz algun tipo de log para visualizarlo

Comment: ¿Cual es el código de `index2.php`?

Comment: El index2.php es el segundo código. Se supone que si la variable CONTROL no existe porque no se logueó el usuario debería salir. Salvo que mi lógica esté mal.

Comment: Haz intentado de cambiarlo a una variable de session en vez de define? Ejemplo: `$_SESSION['control'] = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedo observar que nunca llegas a cambiar el valor de la sesión cuando ya se haya realizado el éxito de logueo.

Encima para evaluar si la sesión es diferente de nulo o que determina que está vacía deberías usar: [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) e [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php). Asimismo, podrías usar [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) para destruir la sesión.

Para ello tendrías que modificar:

```
<?php
    require ('includes/config.php');

    if ((!isset($_SESSION['CONTROL']) && empty($_SESSION['CONTROL'])) || $_SESSION['CONTROL'] !== 1) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    else{
       $_SESSION['CONTROL'] = 0; // Asignarle otro valor diferente a 1
       unset($_SESSION['CONTROL']); // o destruirlo
       echo "EXITO";
    }
?>
```

Sobre el manejo de sesiones en php es necesario incluir [`session_start();`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php).

Comment: En includes/config.php está el session_start();

Comment: @Piropeator ¿Por qué el título no está de acorde a tu pregunta?, A.Cedano acaso esa es la razón porque incluye varias respuestas.

Comment: Marqué dos respuestas porque fueron útiles para mi problema. Igual modifiqué el título.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa si no estás usando mal tu función header. Según PHP:

> Recuerde que header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde PHP. **Es un error muy común leer código con funciones como include o require, u otro tipo de funciones de acceso de ficheros que incluyen espacios o líneas en blanco que se muestran antes de llamar a la función header()**. Sucede el mismo problema cuando se utiliza un solo fichero PHP/HTML.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Revisa si lo primero que muestras es tu encabezado, como dice el texto indicado y que antes del mismo no estás introduciendo absolutamente nada, siquiera un mínimo espacio en cualquier parte del código, para que se muestre en pantalla.

Por otra parte, el log te está diciendo que la Constante CONTROL ya está definida en tu archivo login.php . Si es el mismo valor no hace falta que la definas de nuevo, si es un valor diferente conviene que le des un nombre diferente.

¿Has revisado el archivo login.php?

Este hilo también podría serte de utilidad: [PHP y la función header(location: )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19791/php-y-la-funci%C3%B3n-headerlocation)

Si es posible, revisa el código fuente de la página cuando intentas abrirla quizá puedas ver si hay algo antes del header.

**Actualización**

Yo revisaría la configuración del archivo .htaccess en las carpetas raíz donde se encuentran los archivos que estás usando, especialmente index2.php

Miraría también el archivo includes/config.php

En alguna parte el flujo entra en un bucle del que no puede salir. Como se sugiere en un comentario, revisa los logs y si no encuentras nada, repasa el código de tus archivos en el orden en que deberían aparecer.

Ya que el mensaje de error sugiere limpiar los cookies, intentaría borrando todos los datos del explorador si es posible, o abriendo una sesión privada del mismo, eso ayuda a veces a depurar posibles cosas que pueden quedarse en memoria.

Comment: El archivo login.php recibe user y password, Si existen en la base de datos se hace define('CONTROL', '1'); y el header redirecciona el código para ejecutar index2.php. Y lo primero que hace en index2.php es verificar que CONTROL haya sido definido.

Comment: El Warning te dice que estás intentando definir una 2ª vez la constante CONTROL. Aunque no sea un error, es un indicativo de que algo falla en la lógica de tu programa. ¿Revisaste lo del header, que no haya nada antes? Para evitar este tipo de problemas se recomienda usar un modelo MVC, de forma que tengas por separado los elementos de tu programa, pero esa es otra historia.

Comment: Cambié en index2.php la línea header("Location: index2.php"); por header("Location: index.php"); Pues allí entraba en el bucle infinito. Ahora no bota error. Pero me regresa al formulario. Es decir mi problema es la variable CONTROL.