# header (location) no redireciona

Tags: php, pdo

según mi programa si ingreso un usuario o contraseña que no esta registrado debería redireccionarme nuevamente a la pagina de login hasta que ingrese un usuario valido, pero no lo ase en su lugar va a la pagina **comprueba_login.php** y se queda y no retorna.. pero no lo hace.
**formulario login.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Ingresa tus datos</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <form class="" action="comprueba_login.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Usuario</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" name="login">
              <label for="">Contraseña</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" name="password"><br>
              <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success">Ingresar</button>
              <button type="reset" name="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>

            </div>


          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**comprueba_login.php**

```
    <?php
try {

  $base = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas;charset=utf8","root","root");

  $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sql = "select * from usuarios_pass where usuario = :login and password = :password";
  $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);
  $login = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['login']));
  $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['password']));

  $resultado->bindValue(":login",$login);
  $resultado->bindValue(":password",$password);
  $resultado->execute();

  if ($resultado->rowCount() !=0){
    //echo "usuario registrado";
  }else{
    header ('location:login.php');
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ("Error al conectar" . $e->getMessage());
}


?>
```

**Directorio de proyecto :**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @jeancarlo733 debe ser porque no encuentra el archivo login.php

Comment: @x-rw y como puedo verificar eso, intento redirigir a google de la siguiente forma `header("Location:http://www.google.com"); `, pero tampoco funciona

Comment: puedes publicar el arbol de tu proyecto?

Comment: lo añado al post espero sea lo que me preguntaste :D

Comment: mmm prueba con `./login.php`o `/login.php`

Comment: acabo de probar `header ('location:./login.php');`y sin el punto y tampoco funciona no entiendo :(

Comment: pon `ob_start();` al comienzo de tu archivo

Comment: tampoco funciona :o

Comment: escribe con mayuscula la `l` de `Location`

Comment: tampoco lo acabo de colocar de esta forma de pronto sea que no encuentra el archivo. `header('Location: http://www.google.com/');`

Comment: @jeancarlos733 Asegurate que no exista **nada antes de la etiqueta `<?php`**, ni un espacio, ni un salto de línea, nada... Además, siempre debe ser una ruta absoluta `Location: http://...`.

Comment: Relacionado: [PHP y la función header(location: )](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/19937/127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato para redirigir es

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Que en tu caso sería

```
header('Location: login.php');
```

Puede que esa sutil diferencia genere el error. Pero también puede que, dada tu esctructura de carpetas, la ubicación interna de `login.php`, que es relativa a `comprueba_login.php` sea distinta a la url con que lo sirves.

Podrías probar con

```
header('Location: http://localhost/1login_pdo/login.php');
```

O la url absoluta que corresponda dependiendo de dónde pusiste el root de tu proyecto.

Comment: Sólo se permiten URLs absolutas en una redirección

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Pozo para mi

Answer (score 1):

intenta con:

```
<?php "<script> window.location.replace('login.php') </script>" ?>
```

Comment: Listo! me ah funcionado .. pero no entiendo el porque no funciona con el header :(

Comment: @jeancarlos733 El espacio en blanco antes de `<?php` es un error al escribir la pregunta o lo tienes en tu código? Si lo tienes en tu código, eso provoca que las cabeceras se envíen al cliente antes de llegar a la función `header` y por lo tanto, no tengan validez. Para evitar este tipo de problemas, es conveniente usar la [caché del búfer de salida](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: No olvides marcar como solucionado indicado la respuesta correcta. @jeancarlos733

Comment: Hola amigo... tenias toda la razón ese espacio en blanco fue el problema gracias .