# Deseo saber como redirigir al homepage

Tags: php

Deseo cambiar la redirección que actualmente manda a la misma pagina, y deseo que te mande a la pagina de inicio.

```
 $redirect = esc_url(wpneo_post('current_page'));
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: no entiend, es PHP o Java?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [PHP y la función header(location: )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19791/php-y-la-funci%c3%b3n-headerlocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header( 'Location: /' ); exit(0);

Answer (score 0):

header( 'Location: /index.php' ); exit(0);

header( 'Location: /index.html' ); exit(0);

puedes meter esto en un if si deseas que si tiene una condicion lo rediriga a home

Answer (score 0):

La forma más rápida es con la función header:

```
header("Location: [ruta_de_la_página]");
die();
```

en tu caso si quieres dirigir al `index.php` **y** se encuentra en el mismo directorio sería:

```
header("Location: ./index.php");
die();
```

espero que te sirva.

Comment: La forma correcta de redirigir es **siempre** con la URL completa.