# Problemas con el path de require_once() en php

Tags: php, rutas

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente que me esta costando descifrar.
Los archivos los tengo distribuidos de la siguiente manera:

```
/
|___control
|     |___usuarios.php
|___vista
      |___addUser.php
|___modelo
|     |___conexion.php
|___index.php
```

Pasa lo siguiente, tanto el archivo "addUser.php" como "index.php" utilizan el archivo "usuarios.php". El archivo "usuarios.php" tiene un `require_once()` del archivo "conexion.php".

Y como "addUser.php" y "index.php" se encuentran en distintos lugares del proyecto, crea conflictos el `_path_` que se agrega en el `require_once()` de "usuarios.php".

¿Alguna idea de cómo resolver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personalmente, para evitar problemas, es mejor usar rutas absolutas. Se adaptan mejor a cualquier implementación, incluso si se cambia de entorno (pero manteniendo la misma estructura).

Ya que no se especifica en la pregunta, pongo como ejemplo una ruta absoluta como esta: `/var/www/httpdocs`

Y el caso real que describes, que tanto *addUser.php* como *index.php*, usan a *usuarios.php*.

```
.
├── index.php
├── control
│   └── usuarios.php
└── vista
    └── addUser.php
```

Llegados a este punto planteamos tres opciones:

1. Usamos rutas relativas
2. Usamos rutas absolutas con texto
3. Usamos rutas absolutas mediante constantes predefinidas

**Opción 1 - Rutas relativas**

Son las que estás usando y con excepción ciertos casos, suele ocasionar los problemas que estás encontrando. Lanzando el error de que no encuentra el fichero solicitado.

*addUser.php*

```
include_once '../control/usuarios.php';
```

*index.php*

```
include_once './control/usuarios.php';
```

**Opción 2 - Rutas absolutas con texto**

Las rutas apuntan siempre al fichero, independientemente desde que nivel se le incluya y siempre que no se cambie la estructura.

Esto resolvería el problema que tienes, pero tiene el inconveniente de que si cambias a otro entorno, con una ruta de ejemplo como la siguiente `/var/www/midominio` se deben cambiar todas las rutas de todos los ficheros. Es algo tedioso de mantener.

*addUser.php*

```
include_once '/var/www/httpdocs/control/usuarios.php';
```

*index.php*

```
include_once '/var/www/httpdocs/control/usuarios.php';
```

**Opción 3 - Rutas absolutas mediante constantes predefinidas**

Personalmente creo que es la más recomendada y sencilla de mantener. Si mantienes la estructura y la cambias de entorno, probablemente produce pocos o ningún error.

La [constante](http://php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__` retorna la ruta absoluta del directorio donde se encuentra el fichero que la está utilizando. Y `dirname()` retorna el directorio padre, en combinación `dirname(__DIR__)` nos retornaría la ruta absoluta del directorio padre donde se encuentra el fichero que la está usando.

*addUser.php*

```
// /var/www/httpdocs/control/usuarios.php
include_once dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/control/usuarios.php';

// Es equivalente a:
// include_once __DIR__ . '/../control/usuarios.php';
```

*index.php*

```
// /var/www/httpdocs/control/usuarios.php
include_once __DIR__ . '/control/usuarios.php';
```

> Como nota, tanto `__DIR__` como `dirname()` terminan las rutas sin la barra **/** al final. Así que, tanto para entrar en los directorios `/dir/...`, como para salir de ellos `/../dir/...` hay que armar la ruta empezando con una barra **/**.

*Si encuentran errores comenten y edito*

Comment: Buenísimo, me quitaste la duda, de hecho estuve viendo en varios blogs sobre estas funciones que comentaste. Pero ahora ya se como aplicar en mi caso. Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas facil es que al direccion del archivo que requieras sea completa por ejemplo: para mi servidor

> require_once("html/aplicacion/new/usuarios/modelo/conexion.php");

y no:

> require_once("../modelo/conexion.php");