# Problema con ruta de archivos PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
 </head>
<body>
    <?php
    require_once "Sistema Web/Data.php";

    $d = new Data();

    $productos = $d->getProductos();

    foreach ($productos as $p) {
      echo $p->id." - ".$p->nombre." - ".$p->precio." - ".$p->stock;
      echo "<br>";
  }

   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

No entiendo porque me sale ese error asumo que tiene que ver algo con las rutas de los archivos pero los tengo en la carpeta www/Sistema Web.

[image: <code>[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]</code>]

Comment: ¿En que directorio se encuentra el archivo desde el que estas haciendo el require?

Comment: En wamp/www/Sistema Web

Comment: Puede que esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75917/5984) te ayude

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes todos tus archivos en el directorio `wamp/www/Sistema Web` en la parte donde colocas la ruta deberia quedar así:

`require_once "Data.php";`

Si tienes que acceder a la carpeta donde esta el archivo seria como lo tienes:

`TuDirectorio/Data.php`

Se recomienda no usar espacios en nombres de directorios como el nombre que le pusiste a

`wamp/www/Sistema Web`

Deberias renombrarlo a `wamp/www/Sistema_Web` o `wamp/www/SistemaWeb` sin espacios