# Ruta absoluta en require

Tags: php

Tengo una duda simple pero que no encuentro solución

Quiero obtener un archivo desde cualquier parte de mi aplicación, utilizando en `include` una ruta absoluta, he probado de varias maneras pero no lo consigo. De todas formas quería saber si existe alguna forma mejor que las que estoy utilizando

```
require "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/application/config.php";
// Esto devuelve: require(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
// Estoy trabajando en local por lo que me imagino que sólo tenga que configurar xampp para esto

require $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/application/config.php";
// Así no me funciona tampoco
```

Comment: Para casos como estos yo suelo definir constantes en cascada empezando desde el root, hasta cada carpeta, sub-carpeta, etc. Lo explico en el apartado [**"Otra posiblidad"** de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967).

Comment: Yo suelo usar constantes predefinidas que se implementan bien y suelen ser bastante estables incluso si cambias de entorno. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75917/5984) tienes algunos ejemplos que creo pueden ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No deberías usar `require` en URLs, aunque sean del mismo dominio.

Por un lado te ahorras una llamada al servidor web innecesaria (incluida la latencia que agregas por ello).

Por otro lado, incluirás la interpretación del archivo PHP, y no su contenido. Por lo que esa probable que, simplemente, ese `require` no tenga absolutamente ningún efecto (la interpretación del PHP con solo código suele ser una página en blanco).

Si no quieres usar rutas relativas:

```
require __DIR__ ."/application/config.php";
```

Entonces deberías probar a agregar una variable de entorno en el servidor web Apache haciendo uso de [`mod_env`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html) con dicha ruta creando un archivo `.htaccess` en el directorio raíz de tu sitio web con este contenido (recuerda activar `AllowOverride FileInfo` si no lo has hecho ya):

```
SetEnv RUTA_BASE /var/www/html/
```

Y, posteriormente, puedes hacer uso de ella en todos los scripts PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
require getenv('RUTA_BASE') ."./application/config.php";
```

Ten en cuenta que si no está definida la variable de entorno, se accederá al subdirectorio `application` a partir del directorio de trabajo gracias al `.` del principio. Si no se pone entonces, por defecto, buscaría el directorio en el raíz del sistema.

Este método te permite tener disponible la ruta en todos los scripts PHP del sitio web de manera automática, sin tener que incluir ningún script de configuración ni nada por el estilo.

Answer (score 0):

ya intentaste concatenando con comillas simples.

require "http://" . ´$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]´ . "/application/config.php";