# login no redirecciona en servidor

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un login ya probado en localhost que me funciona y al subirlo al servidor no me redirecciona a "index.php", al ingresar el user y el pass, sino que luego de enviar la petición al servidor debo editar en la URL el "login.php" a "index.php" para ingresar y efectivamente me carga la sesión

```
<?php


$alert = '';

if(!empty($_POST))
{
if(empty($_POST["user"]) || empty($_POST["pass"]))
{
$alert = 'Ingrese su usuario y contrase;a';
}else{
require_once "conn.php"; 

$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE user = '$user' 
AND pass = '$pass'");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($result > 0) 
{
  $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['active'] = true;
  $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
  $_SESSION['user'] = $data['user'];
  $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
  $_SESSION['rol'] = $data['rol'];



  header("location:index.php");

  }else{
    $alert = 'El usuario o la clave son incorrectos';

      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Posiblemente hay alguna configuración en el servidor remoto que es distinta a la de tu local, como por ejemplo el nivel de errores que se despliega, o el flag de imprimir errores por pantalla. Tal vez después del login aparece un E_NOTICE, lo cual equivale a imprimir contenido en pantalla, lo cual implica que cualquier header que mandes de ahí en adelante no tenga efecto.

Comment: Mira este post (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19791/php-y-la-funci%C3%B3n-headerlocation), quizas pueda solucionarte la duda.

Comment: Cambie la version del php a 7 y se ha arreglado, aunque dudo que sea el motivo de igual forma ese post es muy interesante gracias!