# Error con el header en servidor (php)

Tags: php, servidor, headers

Subi mi proyecto a un servidor, y cuando me tiene que redireccionar para algun lado, a traves de un header, no me funciona, me arroja el siguiente error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd5/429/17353429/public_html/php/conexion.php:10) in /storage/ssd5/429/17353429/public_html/php/check.php on line 31` y antes cuando lo ejecutaba en servidor local con Xampp me andaba perfectamente, alguna ayuda? dejo uno de mis codigos que no funcionan debajo:

```
<?php
session_start();

include "./conexion.php";
if (isset($_POST['email'])  &&  isset($_POST['password'])) {
    
    $resultado = $conexion->query("select * from usuario where
    email='".$_POST['email']."' and 
    password='".sha1($_POST['password'])."' limit 1")or die($conexion->error);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0) {
        $datosUsuario = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);
        $nombre = $datosUsuario[1];
        $idUsuario = $datosUsuario[0];
        $emailUsuario = $datosUsuario[3];
        $imagenPerfil = $datosUsuario[5];
        $nivel = $datosUsuario[6];
        $_SESSION['datos_login']=array(
            'nombre' =>$nombre,
            'idUsuario' =>$idUsuario,
            'emailUsuario' =>$emailUsuario,
            'imagenPerfil' =>$imagenPerfil,
            'nivel' =>$nivel
        );
        if ($nivel == 'admin') {
            header("Location: ../admin/index.php");
        }else{
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
    }else{
        header("Location: ../login.php?error=Credenciales incorrectas");
    }


}else{
    header("../login.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [session\_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)

Comment: El mensaje es claro: en la línea `10`  de `conexion.php` está saliendo algo por pantalla. ¿Qué hay en esa línea? Debes tener claro que NADA puede salir por pantalla antes de los encabezados (ni `echo`, ni `die`, ni `print`, ni `print_r`, ni `var_dump`  ni nigún otro comando de impresión o bloque de contenido html), por tanto, debes tener un control estricto del flujo de tu código.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [PHP y la función header(location: )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19791/php-y-la-funci%c3%b3n-headerlocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente mensaje te da pistas del error

```
(output started at /storage/ssd5/429/17353429/public_html/php/conexion.php:10)
```

En particular te dice que en el archivo `conexion.php` en la línea 10 se imprimió información, y para que "header location" funcione, no se debe haber impreso nada.

Como recomendación, cuando tus archivos sean solo PHP, no necesitas poner la etiqueta de cierre `?>`

Como otra recomendación, mucho cuidado con la siguiente línea

```
$resultado = $conexion->query("select * from usuario where
    email='".$_POST['email']."' and 
    password='".sha1($_POST['password'])."' limit 1")or die($conexion->error);
```

Asegúrate de sanitizar `$_POST['email']` antes de concatenarlo directo en tu query, ya que como lo tienes es propenso a SQL Injection.

Comment: Antes que nada, bienvenido! gracias por tu ayuda y recomendaciones, guiándome en tu respuesta llegue a lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cierto es un error típico a veces un espacio o una etiqueta html lo va a producir. Una forma de evitarlo es colocar en el php.ini la directiva output_buffering = 4096
(4096 es el valor por defecto y va bien). ESto abre un buffer para que php pueda llenarlo antes de sacar valores, pero el efecto colateral de las cabeceras vienen muy bien.