# como puedo solucionar este error de session_start():

Tags: php8

Error:

> session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in /storage/ssd1/300/21164300/public_html/app/templates/header.php on line 2
> El error sale al pasar de una pagina en la q edito al index..ambas paginas tienen este header y el error me da al mostrar el msj q debe salir cuando edito..el msj sale por el swetalert...ya probe sin poner el sesion start pero entonces no se me guarda la variable sesion y si incuyo el codigo del header antes de hacer la operacion de bd me da otro warning y no manda el msj...Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd1/300/21164300/public_html/app/templates/header.php:7) in /storage/ssd1/300/21164300/public_html/app/secciones/usuarios/editar.php on line 37

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia...

```
<?php
session_start();
$base_url="http://localhost/app/";
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){//si no existe un usuario se redirecciona a login
    header("Location:". $base_url ."./login.php");
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>CRUD</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.2.1 -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- para trabjar con jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- para dar estilo y funcionabilidad a la tabla -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>   
    <!-- sweetalert -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script src="../functions.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="nobackbutton();">
    <header>
        <!-- place navbar here -->
    </header>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#" aria-current="page">Sistema <span class="visually-hidden">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $base_url;?>secciones/empleados/">Empleados</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $base_url;?>secciones/puestos/">Puestos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $base_url;?>secciones/usuarios/">Usuarios</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $base_url;?>cerrar.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    <main class="container">

    <!-- verifico si se mando algun msj -->
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['mensaje'])) {?>
    <script>
            Swal.fire({icon:'success', title:'<?php echo $_SESSION['mensaje'];?>'});
    </script>
<?php unset($_SESSION['mensaje']);}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera solucioné el problema que me daba en el **hosting**:

> session_start():  A session had already been started..

Este es el código en la página de editar. Lo que agregué es el código que está debajo de `header("Location:index.php");`

```
<?php 
    include("../../db.php");

    if (isset($_GET['txtId'])) {//preguntamos si existe algun id con isset
        $txtId= (isset($_GET['txtId']))?$_GET['txtId']:"";

        //preparamos la eliminacion en la bd
        $sentencia=$conexion -> prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE id=:id");

         //asignando los valores q vienen del met get
        $sentencia->bindParam(":id",$txtId);
        $sentencia->execute();
        $registro=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);//guarda los resultados en un array
        $usuario=$registro['usuario'];
        $password=$registro['password'];
        $correo=$registro['correo'];

    }

    if($_POST){

        $txtId= (isset($_POST['txtId']))?$_POST['txtId']:"";
        $usuario=(isset($_POST["usuario"]) ? $_POST["usuario"] : "");
        $password=(isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : "");
        $correo=(isset($_POST["correo"]) ? $_POST["correo"] : "");

        //preparamos la insercion en la bd
        $sentencia=$conexion -> prepare("UPDATE tbl_usuarios SET usuario=:usuario, password=:password, correo=:correo  WHERE id=:id");

        //asignando los valores q vienen del met post
        $sentencia->bindParam(":usuario",$usuario);
        $sentencia->bindParam(":password",$password);
        $sentencia->bindParam(":correo",$correo);
        $sentencia->bindParam(":id",$txtId);
        $sentencia->execute();
        
        header("Location:index.php");
        session_start();
        $mensaje="Registro actualizado";
        $_SESSION['mensaje'] =$mensaje;
        exit();
        
    }
    
?>

<?php include("../../templates/header.php");?>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Has consultado preguntas similares que ya han sido respondidas [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=session%20already%20started)?

Si ninguna de esas se corresponde con tu caso, puedes probar a rodear tu llamada a `session_start()` con un bloque if que compruebe si la sesión ya se ha abierto anteriormente (lo cual es muy probable según lo que describes si tanto tu index como tu edit contienen el mismo header que abre la sesión)

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: El problema es q en mi localhost me funciona bien el codigo pero en el host q uso q es 000webhost me da esos errores....si no pongo el sesion start no me guarda la variable sesion y va vacia al index...si pongo el header primero q ya tiene el sesion start antes de hacer las operaciones de bd cuando hago el header location me edita pero no me va al index y muestra el msj cuando cancelo

Comment: Entonces es que el host te está generando algo de HTML sin que te des cuenta. Aquí puedes ver algunas opciones para solucionarlo, como hacer la redirección con javascript https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/19791/5896

Comment: Ya resolvi usando este codigo debajo del header ()----- session_start();
        $mensaje="Registro actualizado";
        $_SESSION['mensaje'] =$mensaje;
        exit();

Comment: ` header("Location:index.php");
        session_start();
        $mensaje="Registro actualizado";
        $_SESSION['mensaje'] =$mensaje;
        exit();`

Comment: Bien hecho. Puedes añadir ese código como una respuesta, en lugar de aquí en los comentarios :-)

Comment: no se muy bien...q hago doy en el boton q dice responde tu propia pregunta?